# During a domain auction for the .com version of my domain, it redirects to my site

Tags: domains

I own a web domain that is quite well known in certain circles. The .com of the same name is now being auctioned off at a price I certainly do to wish to pay.

The person in question is auto redirecting their .com domain to my website during the auction. So it looks like this persons .com is owned by and/or is in some way related to my company and website. In effect using my website as the content for this persons domain auction.

For example: If some random person bought `pepsi.com` by luck and put it to auction with an auto-redirect to the official Pepsi company. Would that be legal?  Obviously my company is minuscule compared to Pepsi. Still, this all seems completely wrong to me.

Answer (score 3):

There is one thing you can do quickly with some options depending upon how nice you want to be.

If you want to be nice, create a webpage that briefly and in bold letters explains what is going on. Then use something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*baddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.com/bugger-off.html [F,L]
```

If you do not feel like being nice you can just block them which is probably what I would do. The reason why I would chose the *not so nice route* is that I do not want search engines being confused though I am not sure how confused they would be.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^.*baddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

The first example redirects anyone with the referrer of the bad domain name to the page bugger-off.html. Of course you can change the full URL reference to a shorter one and of course the page does not have to be bugger off. I just like the name. (gotta have a sense of humor these days...)

The second example provides a 403 Forbidden error and no page.

Comment: * Thank you closetnoc. I have tried to vote your answer up, but I am not allowed. it is really good of you to go into detail. I wonder if it is legal to do this under iccan regulations?

Comment: I do not know if there is a rule for what they are doing. The ICANN site is not so clear, but here is a link: https://new.icann.org/resources/pages/complaints-2013-03-22-en. I appreciate the attempt to up vote the answer. You are certainly able to block these access. That is full within your rights.

Comment: Thank you very much closenoc, thats great, i shall have a read through  : )

Comment: Anytime. That's why I am here. You may be able to file a complaint or at least try. They may not be the right ones to talk to, but maybe they can help anyway. This is such an odd case. I have never heard of such a thing before.